# Is it necessary to add `index_together` same as `ordering` in Django model meta?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Would Django handle `ordering` smartly by adding union index? Like:

```
from django.db import models

class Musician(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'instrument']
        index_together = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'instrument']
```

Is there performance difference with/without the last line `index_togeter` declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Django doesn't do it itself. Because you can have separate indexes for each field or one multi-column index. Your multi-column index won't work if you try to order just by `last_name` or `instrument`. So it is up to you to specify which index do you need.